# Binding multiple TextBoxes to different properties of one Object, MVVM, C#

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, caliburn.micro

Here is my object in the Model:

```
public class Object
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Property1 { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my object in the ViewModel:

```
private Object_object;

public string Object
{
   get { return _object; }
   set 
   { 
       _object = value; 
       NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Object);
   }
}
```

I am using Caliburn Micro as my MVVM framework.

Here is my XAML in the View:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Object.Property1, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I would like to bind the TextBox value to a property of an object. This way when I pass the object to another ViewModel, I am passing one Object, not numerous properties. Is this possible, or do I need to just create a new property as type `string`?

Answer (score 0):

First off, declaring your class "Object" is basically overwriting the DEFAULT base class of Object.  Give it some more realistic name even if 'MyTestObject'

Define your custom class

```
public class MyTestObject
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Property1 { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Implement in your view model

```
private MyTestObject _myBindToTestObject;

public MyTestObject MyBindToTestObject
{
   get { return _myBindToTestObject; }
   set 
   { 
       _myBindToTestObject = value; 
       NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyTestObject);
   }
}
```

Finally bind to the form

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyBindToTestObject.Property1, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Binding goes to the publicly exposed object name "MyBindToTestObject" and then the specific property on that object.

Comment: Sorry. My `Object` naming is not my actual name, I'm just using it for example purposes. I don't think using the `NotifyOfPropertyChange()` will work for the type. I think I would have to use the type name `MyBindToTestObject`, no? If my understanding is correct, that is like notifying `string` or `int`.

Comment: I am able to bind to properties that have a type of `string` or `int`, but not those that are of object (i.e., `MyTestObject`) and binding to a specific property in that object (see xaml).

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke NotifyOfPropertyChanged each time the individual Property of your Custom Object Changes. For example,

```
public class Foo : PropertyChangedBase
{
        private string property1;
        private string property2;
        private int id;

        public int Id
        {
            get => id; 
            set
            {
                id = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Id));
            }
        }
        public string Property1
        {
            get => property1; 
            set
            {
                property1 = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Property1));
            }
        }
        public string Property2
        {
            get => property2; 
            set
            {
                property2 = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(property2));
            }
        }
}
```

Now you could use the binding to the individual property of the Custom Object.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FooInstance.Property2}"></TextBox>
```